# Do applications install for all users or only for one?

Tags: macos, applications, install, permission, dmg

If I install a application using *.dmg image using user user1, it will be available when user2 log in as well? or it will be available only for user1 ?

Comment: Is just an app icon you drag to a folder icon, or is it an installer?

Answer (score 8):

It depends where it installs to.

If it goes into the main Applications folder, then yes, it's available to all users - though each user will have their own distinct prefs, saved under their account.

If it's installed to /Users/[your name]/Applications, then it's only available to that user.

Comment: How I can know where it will be installed before installing ?

Comment: Most apps you simply drag from the open .dmg to where you wish. If it has an installer, it may ask. 99 out of 100 will default to shared Applications.

Comment: @username23423 You can also check using [Pacifist.](http://www.charlessoft.com)