# What's the most appropriate directory where to place 'development software' and 'files' shared between users?

Tags: filesystem, user-account, folders, sharing, file

In Linux (`Ubuntu` in my case) if exists many users, each one with its home directory, such as:

- `/home/alpha`
- `/home/beta`
- `/home/omicron`

to share *development software* and *files* between/among users I've already solved that through:

- [What's the most appropriate directory where to place development software shared between users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362838/whats-the-most-appropriate-directory-where-to-place-development-software-shared) - `/opt`
- [What's the most appropriate directory where to place files shared between users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/whats-the-most-appropriate-directory-where-to-place-files-shared-between-users) - `/srv`

But it in MacOS? What is the current standard to accomplish the same goal? It for both scenarios.

Comment: What do you consider 'development software' & how does it differ from any other software? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312058/do-applications-install-for-all-users-or-only-for-one Shared files can go in the /Users/Shared directory.

Comment: Asking two questions that are opinion based might yield dozens of answers that mix opinions on both questions. Can you edit this so it’s asking one question?

Comment: I find the Shared directory works, especially useful with my kids and photos galore...

Comment: About 'development software' it is about of non `.dmg` installers, consider for example Maven, Gradle. They are available through .gz and .zip formats respetively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standards as such. Things which might work are

- /Users/Shared — especially for generally used data
- /usr/local — for locally installed stuff
- /opt — also for locally installed stuff

Traditionally, `/usr/local` is used for unix-style installations where stuff goes directly to bin, man, etc, share, lib etc; while `/opt` is used for package installations where e.g. Oracle installs into `/opt/oracle` and `/opt/oracle/bin` is added to PATH.